# Making a black hole with only energy

Tags: general-relativity

If I take a trillion kilograms of matter and, with my personal asteroid-crushing machine, compress it down to length scales below a femtometer, then the escape velocity at the surface of the mass would be equal to the speed of light: It would become a black hole.

$$ Schwarzschild \space radius = \frac{2Gm}{c^2} $$
$$ 2 * 6 * 10^{-11} * 10^{12} * 10^{-18} * 3^{-2} ≈ 10^{-15} $$

Ok, what if I took a femtometer capacitor and stored an equivalent amount of energy in its electric field $E_{eq} = mc^2 = 10^{12} * 9 * 10^{18} = 9 * 10^{30} J $? Would that become a black hole too?

More generally, suppose you have an amount of mass $m$. Does the amount of energy equivalent to $m$ have all the space properties as the mass? Does it bend the time-space continuum?

Comment: It depends. Energy does bend spacetime, but not necessarily the same way as mass. For example, photons do not generate static gravity. The gravitational field of the photon is a gravitational wave perpendicular to the direction of the photon. As both move with the speed of light, the wave appears associated with the spacetime event of the photon emission. I believe you could create a black hole, if you magage to localize enough energy (e.g. in a tiny mirror box), but not by just focusing a laser beam, whose source is outside of the region.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it would.

In general relativity the spacetime curvature is related not just to the mass, but to an object called the [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor). Under most circumstances the dominant term in the tensor is the matter/energy density and no distinction is made between matter and energy. They are treated as equivalent and related by Einstein's famous equation $E=mc^2$.

For example [the kugelblitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelblitz_(astrophysics)) is a black hole created just from light.

The *mass* of a black hole is actually a somewhat elusive quantity since the well known Schwarzschild and Kerr geometries are actually vacuum solutions and contain no matter or energy at all. The mass of these geometries is actually a geometric property called the [ADM mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism#ADM_energy_and_mass).

Finally we should note that creating a black hole from energy, or even measuring the gravitational effect of energy remains far, far beyond our experimental boundaries at the moment.